# How to get hive instance details from Beeline using Zookeeper

Tags: hive, apache-zookeeper, beeline

I am using a ZK string and connecting to the Hive instances. There are 6 hive instances mentioned in the ZK string all with port 2181. 3 of them are running in http mode and 3 in binary. I want to check to which hive instance my Beeline is connected to and what mode I am using.

I can get the details of the transport mode which the instance uses (*set hive.server2.transport.mode*).

I just wanted to know to which instance I am connected to as well. Is there any way I can get the details of the instance to which I am connected to ?

Thanks,

AKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set hive.server2.thrift.bind.host